# How to add custom attributes to user object in Azure AD which can be accessed with SAML based SSO?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I want to integrate Azure AD login into my application using SAML and use a custom user attribute to set roles of that user in my application.
Basically I want to set a custom attribute `my-application-roles` with value `[roles-JSON]` which I will receive in SAML response and will assign it to the user in my system.
I was able to achieve this with G-SUITE SAML integration as mentioned at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208725?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-a-new-custom-attribute.
I did go through below microsoft articles -

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-schema-extensions
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions

But most of the stuff is not very helpfull to me. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this or any other way which I can use to attach some custom data to user object?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization#attributes?

Comment: Not exactly. This actually hard codes that specific attribute for all users. What I want is user level attribute which I can change at user level and so that it gets passed on as claims in SAML response.

Comment: Are you looking to create user attributes? Here is the reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21843/how-to-set-custom-claims-for-a-user-in-azure-ad-b2.html

Comment: @Jit_MSFT The question is similar to mine, but I dont think it has been answered. The given answer talks of user flow where user himself provides the attribute value. But in my case only Admin should be allowed to set these custom attributes.

Comment: My requirement is the same as @Flake
I want to use custom attributes for custom claims which will be set by an admin portal.
I don't get it why the self-signup is requried for this. It is a very simple feature which exists with most of the IAMs (Cognito, Keycloack,..) for a long time.
Microsoft products keep failing me .